# Replace an unresolved type in eclipse jdt after deleting a class with an existing type

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I'm using eclipse jdt to programmatically collapse the hierarchy of a class ( 1. move all methods and fields to the parent class, 2. remove abstract keyword if parent class is abstract,  and 3. reference the parent class instead of the children one in all the system.)
I complete steps 1, 2, but I have issues with 3.
Here is my code:

```
//update the references to the parent class
IPackageFragment classChangedPackage = rootpackage.getPackageFragment("net.sourceforge.ganttproject");
ICompilationUnit ClassChangedCU = classChangedPackage.getCompilationUnit("GanttProject" + ".java");
ASTParser parserClassChanged = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
parserClassChanged.setSource(ClassChangedCU);
parserClassChanged.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parserClassChanged.setResolveBindings(true); // we need bindings later on
final CompilationUnit cuClassChanged = (CompilationUnit) parserClassChanged.createAST(null);
cuClassChanged.recordModifications();
rewrite = ASTRewrite.create(cuClassChanged.getAST());

TypeDeclaration typeDeclClassChanged = (TypeDeclaration) cuClassChanged.types().get(0);                                             
cuClassChanged.accept(new CHtypeVisitor(rewrite,classSourceName,typeDeclClassChanged));
Document doc= new Document(typeDeclClassChanged.toString());
TextEdit edits = rewrite.rewriteAST(doc, null);
try {
edits.apply(doc);
} catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
ClassChangedCU.getBuffer().setContents(doc.get());
```

and my visitor code:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.PrimitiveType;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleType;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewrite;

public class CHtypeVisitor extends ASTVisitor {

private ASTRewrite rewrite;
private String childTypeName;
private TypeDeclaration targetType;

public CHtypeVisitor(ASTRewrite rewrite, String childTypeName, TypeDeclaration targetType) {
super();
this.rewrite = rewrite;
this.childTypeName = childTypeName;
this.targetType = targetType;
}

@Override
public boolean visit(SimpleType node) {
if (node.toString().equals(childTypeName)) {
System.out.println("child type detected: "
+ node.getStartPosition());
// 1
rewrite.replace(node,
rewrite.getAST().newPrimitiveType(PrimitiveType.INT), null);
}
return true;
}

}
```

However, even replacing with a primitive like int does not work.

What I want is to apply programmatically something like the eclipse quickfix (jdt CorrectionEngine) for unresolved types, providing as argument the type that I want to replace (child class) and the replacement (child class).

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: It does not replace the child type by the int primitive

Comment: Do you see the visitor matching the expected node & name? Does the rewriter produce any text edits? Are any exceptions thrown? Is the resulting content of the doc OK?

Comment: Yes, the visitor matches the expected node and name.  The rewriter produces the expected text edit [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77dm5mEsmNEQmV1bVVIdUs0Ym8/view?usp=sharing).  The are no exceptions.  However, I cannot see the content of the doc as is too long and Eclipse trim the text.

Comment: I indirectly search for the type that I was supposed to replace, and noticed that in the resulting content of the doc is wrong, but how is this possible.  I did it through doc.get().contains("PDFExport") that is the type I want to replace and it returns true.   Why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a bug in your code:

The document to which you apply the text edits must have the **exact same content** as the source that was given to the parser.

By contrast, when you create the document from `typeDeclClassChanged.toString()` you are loosing all layout / whitespace information and also comments (except for javadoc).

This will result in text edits applied in wrong positions.

To obtain the correct source content, you should use `ClassChangedCU.getSource()`